# How do I input file name using tkinter in py3

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I don't like how this looks or why it doesn't work

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
root = tkinter.Tk()
filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
  initialdir="E://",
  title="choose file",
  filetypes=(
    ("xhtml files","*.xhtml"),
    ("all files","*.*")
  )
)
```

If there can be better way than tkinter please suggest.

Comment: What  happens when you try the way that is documented to work? How do you define "better way"? What would make the solution better in your opinion? Fewer lines of code? Prettier dialog?

Comment: the code doesnt work plus by better, i mean better UI.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? How is the way it's working different from what you want? Your question is too vague.

Comment: it say "AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'filedialog'"

Comment: maybe its not the way to be used in Python 3.6

Comment: did you name your file "tkinter.py"?

Comment: this seems to work fine both on py2.7 and py3.6

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
fedorov$ python3
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:01:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter 
>>> from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
>>> root = tkinter.Tk()
>>> tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "E://",title = "choose file",filetypes = (("xhtml files","*.xhtml"),("all files","*.*")))
'/Users/fedorov/Desktop/IMG_0656.jpg.xhtml'
```

What are you expecting?